# MySQL Locate a 1st lowercase letter inside a string

Tags: mysql, sql, string

Is there any way using MySQL statements to find the location where the 1st lowercase letter appears ?
for example, I would like to get the number 7 (the location of the 1st lowercase letter "a")
should I run the needed statements on the string

> "MARY Had a little lamb"

Comment: What is the charset and collation defined for the specific field/column in which you are trying to find the lowercase letter ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexp_instr()` (at least in MySQL 8+).  However, you need a case sensitive collation:

```
select regexp_instr('MARY Had a little lamb' collate utf8mb4_bin, '[a-z]')
```